# Is there a way to create NA conditionally on a row? R

Tags: r, database, function, dataframe, dplyr

I have this dummy dataset and I would like to transform a column, conditionally depending on the rows.

Here is the dataset.

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(year = c(2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 
2019, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2012, 2013, 
2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 
2017, 2018, 2019, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 
2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2012, 2013, 2014, 
2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019), id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 
7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7), apv = c("Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
"Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
"Y", "Y", "N", "NA", "NA", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", 
"N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "NA", "NA", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
"Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "Y", "Y"
), apv_d = c("Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
"Y", "N", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", 
"NA", "NA", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "NA", "NA", "Y", "Y", 
"Y", "N", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
"N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "NA", "NA", "Y", "Y")), row.names = c(NA, 
-56L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

So this is my dataset I just have the variable `apv` and I want to transform said column into `apv_d`

I think I should use a function with a match argument, but I am really lost because I've never done a function before.

---

Edit: The variable `apv` is telling us if the firm is open or closed each period.
So I just want to have the first closure on the firm, if a firm disappears from the panel (case of id=2) I want that `apv`is N denoting the first closure of the firm. If `apv` is closed for more than one period (case id=4) i want to generate NAs

It's like if `apv` is Y keep it like that, but if there are N several times (for the same id) just keep the first and the other ones are NAs.

But take into account the case when id=2 there the first period that is the NA I want it to be N and the rest NA

---

Edit2: Since the answers are working great with the example data, but I have some issues with real data, here is the real data: [real data here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14dtrvqlAhNqjTbnjl2eRh6IuZZy2vYo2/view?usp=sharing)

And the issue in the complete dataset is shown here:

where año=year, ruc=id, nombre is a meaningless variable.
[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  df %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(closure = cumsum(lag(apv) == "Y" & apv != "Y"),
           apv_d2  = case_when(apv == "Y" ~ "Y",
                               closure == 0 ~ apv,
                               closure == 1 & lag(closure) == 0 ~ "N",
                               TRUE ~ "NA"))
```

Result

```
   year id apv apv_d closure apv_d2
1  2012  1   Y     Y       0      Y
2  2013  1   Y     Y       0      Y
3  2014  1   Y     Y       0      Y
4  2015  1   Y     Y       0      Y
5  2016  1   Y     Y       0      Y
6  2017  1   Y     Y       0      Y
7  2018  1   Y     Y       0      Y
8  2019  1   Y     Y       0      Y
9  2012  2   Y     Y       0      Y
10 2013  2   Y     Y       0      Y
11 2014  2   Y     Y       0      Y
12 2015  2  NA     N       1      N
13 2016  2  NA    NA       1     NA
14 2017  2  NA    NA       1     NA
15 2018  2  NA    NA       1     NA
16 2019  2  NA    NA       1     NA
17 2012  3   Y     Y       0      Y
18 2013  3   Y     Y       0      Y
19 2014  3   Y     Y       0      Y
20 2015  3   Y     Y       0      Y
21 2016  3   Y     Y       0      Y
22 2017  3   N     N       1      N
23 2018  3  NA    NA       1     NA
24 2019  3  NA    NA       1     NA
25 2012  4   Y     Y       0      Y
26 2013  4   Y     Y       0      Y
27 2014  4   Y     Y       0      Y
28 2015  4   Y     Y       0      Y
29 2016  4   Y     Y       0      Y
30 2017  4   N     N       1      N
31 2018  4   N    NA       1     NA
32 2019  4   N    NA       1     NA
33 2012  5   Y     Y       0      Y
34 2013  5   Y     Y       0      Y
35 2014  5   Y     Y       0      Y
36 2015  5   N     N       1      N
37 2016  5   N    NA       1     NA
38 2017  5   N    NA       1     NA
39 2018  5  NA    NA       1     NA
40 2019  5  NA    NA       1     NA
41 2012  6   Y     Y       0      Y
42 2013  6   Y     Y       0      Y
43 2014  6   Y     Y       0      Y
44 2015  6   Y     Y       0      Y
45 2016  6   Y     Y       0      Y
46 2017  6   Y     Y       0      Y
47 2018  6   N     N       1      N
48 2019  6   Y     Y       1      Y
49 2012  7   Y     Y       0      Y
50 2013  7   Y     Y       0      Y
51 2014  7   Y     Y       0      Y
52 2015  7   N     N       1      N
53 2016  7   N    NA       1     NA
54 2017  7   N    NA       1     NA
55 2018  7   Y     Y       1      Y
56 2019  7   Y     Y       1      Y
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a small helper function and apply it for each `id`.

```
generate_result <- function(apv) {
  inds <- apv == 'N' | apv == 'NA'
  apv[inds & !duplicated(inds)] <- 'N'
  apv[inds & duplicated(inds)] <- 'NA'
  apv
}

library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(apv_res = generate_result(apv)) %>% ungroup
```

This returns -

```
   year id apv apv_d apv_res
1  2012  1   Y     Y       Y
2  2013  1   Y     Y       Y
3  2014  1   Y     Y       Y
4  2015  1   Y     Y       Y
5  2016  1   Y     Y       Y
6  2017  1   Y     Y       Y
7  2018  1   Y     Y       Y
8  2019  1   Y     Y       Y
9  2012  2   Y     Y       Y
10 2013  2   Y     Y       Y
11 2014  2   Y     Y       Y
12 2015  2  NA     N       N
13 2016  2  NA    NA      NA
14 2017  2  NA    NA      NA
15 2018  2  NA    NA      NA
16 2019  2  NA    NA      NA
17 2012  3   Y     Y       Y
18 2013  3   Y     Y       Y
19 2014  3   Y     Y       Y
20 2015  3   Y     Y       Y
21 2016  3   Y     Y       Y
22 2017  3   N     N       N
23 2018  3  NA    NA      NA
24 2019  3  NA    NA      NA
25 2012  4   Y     Y       Y
26 2013  4   Y     Y       Y
27 2014  4   Y     Y       Y
28 2015  4   Y     Y       Y
29 2016  4   Y     Y       Y
30 2017  4   N     N       N
31 2018  4   N    NA      NA
32 2019  4   N    NA      NA
33 2012  5   Y     Y       Y
34 2013  5   Y     Y       Y
35 2014  5   Y     Y       Y
36 2015  5   N     N       N
37 2016  5   N    NA      NA
38 2017  5   N    NA      NA
39 2018  5  NA    NA      NA
40 2019  5  NA    NA      NA
41 2012  6   Y     Y       Y
42 2013  6   Y     Y       Y
43 2014  6   Y     Y       Y
44 2015  6   Y     Y       Y
45 2016  6   Y     Y       Y
46 2017  6   Y     Y       Y
47 2018  6   N     N       N
48 2019  6   Y     Y       Y
49 2012  7   Y     Y       Y
50 2013  7   Y     Y       Y
51 2014  7   Y     Y       Y
52 2015  7   N     N       N
53 2016  7   N    NA      NA
54 2017  7   N    NA      NA
55 2018  7   Y     Y       Y
56 2019  7   Y     Y       Y
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak, it did work on the example data. But in the real data whenever I have the case that id=2 doesn't generate the N of the first closure. I sent you the real data. I am trying to put it here so Jon can see it too but it's too extensive.

Comment: Yes, agree. But is the exactly case where id=2.

Comment: oh, yes! i thought it was understandable that was a missing value because that's the common R notation. How should I have put those values?

Comment: Okay, I am sorry. Won't happen again.